# how to use torque to control joint

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, may I control the joint using torque like animate_pose as follows, because it just can control the position, I want to add torque to the joint.
thank you
best
guangda

std::map<std::string, common::NumericAnimationPtr> anim;

```
  // Create a new animation for the "my_joint" define in the SDF file.
  // The animation will last for 5.0 seconds, and it will repeat
  anim["box::my_joint"].reset(new common::NumericAnimation(
        "my_animation", 5.0, true));

  // Create a key frame for the starting position of the joint
  common::NumericKeyFrame *key = anim["box::my_joint"]->CreateKeyFrame(0.0);
  key->SetValue(0.0);

  // Create a key frame half-way through the animation
  key = anim["box::my_joint"]->CreateKeyFrame(2.5);
  key->SetValue(-3.14);

  // Create the end key frame to be at the same position as the start
  // for a smooth animation
  key = anim["box::my_joint"]->CreateKeyFrame(5.0);
  key->SetValue(0.0);

 // Attach the animation to the model
  _model->SetJointAnimation(anim);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1850/how-to-use-torque-to-control-joint/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

On a **joint** you can only apply a force, with SetForce. See [here](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.5.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a8da0e864018bc0810bbfcf1e930183a7).

```
model->GetJoint("joint_name")->SetForce(int _index,double _force);
```

If you want to apply torque, you apply it with SetTorque to the **link**. See [here](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.5.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#a85cab66b9c9ba07d411478efab212d5a).
An example:

```
model->GetLink("link_name")->SetTorque(vector3);
```

---UPDATE---

I took the example from [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin) tutorial, you can check it out.

```
...
public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) 
{
  this->model = _parent;

  this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
      boost::bind(&ClassName::OnUpdate, this, _1));
}

public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
{
    // Check duration here, something like:
    // if ((common::Time dt = this->model->GetWorld()->GetSimTime() - last_saved_time) < 5 )
    model->GetLink("link_name")->SetTorque(math::Vector3(0, 0, 0));
}
...
```

Cheers, Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-03-15**:
thank you, I find add a big torque to the link and it move a little, so ,I think this torque just continue a short time, how to maintain this torque for 5 second or more?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-16**:
Then I don't thin you should use animation, you can maintain this torque in the onUpdate function, and if you need a given time you can always check the difference from the simulation time, I will update the answer with a generic example.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-03-16**:
to apply force continuously, call it on every world update, see http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin, replace the calls to "SetLinearVel" with "SetForce" example above.